# Using an Array as argument in Case Select statement

Tags: excel, vba

Based on certain information, my excel file is in a certain 'status'. For example we have the process of an service; (1)request, (2)process, (3)payment.
After checking if all the information is provided a function returns a 1 or a 0. 1 is all the information is present, 0 if it is not.

```
Dim Status(1 to 3) as Integer

CheckFunction(Request)
Status(1)= CheckFunction 'Return 1 
CheckFuntion(Process)
Status(2)= CheckFunction 'Return 1
CheckFuntion(Payment)
Status(3)= CheckFunction 'Return 0
```

Now my array looks like this

```
Status(1, 1, 0)
```

This file should now be in the 'Process' status.
I want to use this so determine the current status of the service, like;

```
Select Case Status()

Case (1, 0, 0)
  'Some code
Case (1, 1, 0)
  'Some code
Case (1, 1, 1)
  'Some code

End Select
```

But i cant get this to work properly. Iv got a total of 15 different statuses and this to me seems to most elegant way to do this.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing arrays cannot be done explicitly - thus the below code gives Type Mismatch (Error 13):

```
Public Sub TestMe()            
    Debug.Print Array(1, 2, 3) = Array(1, 2, 3)            
End Sub
```

Thus arrays are compared by comparing every element of them or by some other business logic (e.g., one may consider that arrays are equal if the first 2 elements are the same or if the size is the same).

---

The simplest solution would be probably to transform the array to a string and to compare this string with another string. Then, this would work:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim status As Variant: status = Array(1, 1, 0)

    Select Case Join(status, "")
        Case "100"
            Debug.Print 100
        Case "110"
            Debug.Print 110
        Case "111"
            Debug.Print 111
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend to compare strings as `Case "100"` to avoid implicit cast of values into strings and don't mess up with `Case 001`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - `Case 001` is a good point. Indeed `010` would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just add up the values:

```
 For each elem in status
     statussum=statussum + elem
 Next
```

Then do your SELECT/CASE on that:

```
 SELECT CASE statussum
     Case 1
     Case 2
     Case 3
 End Select
```

Also, since it doesn't seem likely that you would have `001` or `101` or `011` you could check each element of the array in a SELECT:

```
 If Status(1) = 1 Then
     ...
 ElseIf Status(2) = 1 Then
     ...
 ElseIf Status(3) = 1 Then
     ...
 End If
```

Lastly, in a loop you could detect status. Which would be helpful if you do have instances of `001` or `011` or `101`:

```
 Dim statusCount as Integer, maxStatus as Integer
 For each elem in Status
     statusCount = statusCount + 1
     if elem = 1 then maxStatus = statusCount
 Next elem
 Debug.print maxStatus
```

Comment: The first example will fail because `001`, `010` and `100` have the same sum. You would need to multiply the first item with 100 the second with 10 and the third with 1 and then sum them up.

Comment: I get the impression that the condition with preceding `0` doesn't exist in OP's scenario. That being said I think using an array, in the first place, is probably not the best choice here (if that assumption holds true).

Comment: This was not clear to me, but if that is the case I conclude with you. He could easily count the status up then from state 1 (request) to state 3 (payment) then without using an array.